# Read CSV and assign values to r variables

Tags: r

I'm new to R, and I wonder how to read a csv file and assign the value from the csv file to a variable? For example I have a csv file and I want to assign filename and filepath to R variables. I know how to read csv into R variable with 
    mydata <- read.csv("testing.csv")`

But how to assign value from Filename which is 'globaldata.txt' and Filepath which is 'E:\Test\Global' to r variable

```
variable    value
Filename    globaldata.txt
Filepath    E:\Test\Global
```

Comment: Can you show us the first 2+ lines from your input file `globaldata.txt` ?

Comment: What kind of manipulation do you have in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's safe to use read.table and define the class for each variable in the argument, see the help file ?read.table

```
mydata <- read.table("testing.csv", colClasses = c("character", "character"))
```

The return value mydata will be a data frame, and u can simply extract what you want using the $ sign
e.g.

```
value1 <- mydata$column1
```

etc.

Comment: Hi I able to get the contents from csv file but how to split values to different variables ? my command like this value1 <- mydata$Value

Comment: once i enter value1, the R returned

Comment: [1] "globaldata.txt"                                                        "E:\\Test\\Global"

Comment: i want assign value 222.csv to variable1 and E:\\Report\\Finance\\DataFlow\\GlobalFILES to variable2

Comment: in that case it is because you did not specify a separator between the variables when you used `read.table`. are the values separated by a ",", a ";" , a blank space ? use `sep=";"` in `read.table` if it is a ";" and so on. That will give you 2 columns and not just one

Comment: got it, i can get the column values by variablname[[]]

Comment: why R auto assign \\ slash to file path ?

Comment: Because for a Windows path it is either "/" or "\\". You can't have the "\" used in Windows.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following :

```
Filename<-"globaldata.csv" # if this is a csv and not a .txt file
Filepath<-"E:/Test/Global/" # if you are on Windows you need to use "/"
```

which then allows you to do (if this is what you want)

```
mydata<-read.csv(paste0(Filepath,Filename))
```

**EDIT**

If I understand correctly you have a csv file named testing.csv with two columns: one with Filenames and one with Filepaths.

In that case when you have `mydata<-read.csv("testing.csv")`you have a dataframe with two columns. To access the first one you use `mydata[,1]` and for the second (Filepath) : `mydata[,2]`. If you want the Filename of the third entry in the file you then use `mydata[3,1]`(before the comma is the row, after is the column)

I hope this is what you are looking for, otherwise I'm afraid I misunderstood you again. Having a look at the csv file will help to better understand the question

Comment: i think you are misunderstood. All the variables i will stored into csv file and this will act like mapping file. Now want i want to do is get the content and assgin to R variables